Creating an S-curved Stepper Component
I'm trying to build a custom stepper component with an S-curve shape in React I've explored using the MUI Stepper component but couldn't achieve the desired design. even I tried pure html and CSS also but couldn't make it near.
I'm quite new to web development, so I'm struggling to even create a basic curved line.

looking for documentation, sample code or anything might helpful to create this component.

This question is similar to: Creating s-shaped curve using css. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
